Azure Function in Docker: wwwroot empty
Hi i'm new to azure functions and Docker,i deployed my Azure Function and it work partially, now i would need to access wwwroot directory of Docker container, i tryed access via sftp but directory is empty.
I'm looking on wrong directory?
This is my DockerFile
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated:4-dotnet-isolated8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
EXPOSE 8080

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends gnupg wget curl unzip && \
    wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list && \
    apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends google-chrome-stable && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*

RUN export CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION=$(curl -s "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE"); \
    wget -q --continue -P /chromedriver "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/${CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION}/chromedriver_linux64.zip"; \
    echo ""


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FucntionTestDocker/FucntionTestDocker.csproj", "FucntionTestDocker/"]
RUN dotnet restore "./FucntionTestDocker/FucntionTestDocker.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FucntionTestDocker"
RUN dotnet build "./FucntionTestDocker.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "./FucntionTestDocker.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /home/site/wwwroot
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV AzureWebJobsScriptRoot=/home/site/wwwroot \
    AzureFunctionsJobHost__Logging__Console__IsEnabled=true

An this is my sftp directory

Thnk you in advance

How did you deploy your function to Azure? Also navigate to the kudu site of your functionapphttps://appname.scm.azurewebsites.net/nuewui and check if you can see the files under site/wwwroot.

I deployed with VisualStudio publish, in kudu site if i navigate in wwwroot still empty.

Can you see the deployed function in overview=>functions?

Yes and i can run it too, and it work

Is it linux function app? And which plan?

Yes linux docker and premium plan

You're likely seeing this behaviour because you're accessing the file system of the App Service instance, not the container instance. An App Service Premium Plan runs on a dedicated VM instance. There can be multiple containers running in an App Service instance. When you use sftp you are connecting to the underlying OS file system of the App Service instance. I can tell because the only port exposed in the container is 8080, not the 22 which sftp uses. The container file system is virtualized by the host operating system docker runtime, so you need to use the docker command line tool to access it.
You can do this by accessing the bash shell of the host in Kudu.
Run Bash Shell in Kudu

Access Kudu:

Go to the Azure Portal.
Navigate to your Azure App Service instance.
In the left-hand menu, under "Development Tools," select "Advanced Tools".


Open the Kudu Console:

Click on "Go" under "Advanced Tools." This will open a new tab or window.


Select Bash Shell:

In the Kudu portal, navigate to the "Debug Console" section.
Choose the "Bash" option. This will open a Bash shell within the Kudu interface.



Identify and Connect to Container:

Find Your Container ID or Name:

Run docker ps to list all running containers.
Identify the container ID or name of the container you want to execute commands in.


Execute a Command:

Use docker exec followed by the container ID or name and the command you want to run inside the container.



Example:
Suppose your container ID is 123456789abc and you want to list the contents of the /home/site/wwwroot directory inside the container.
docker exec 123456789abc ls /home/site/wwwroot

This command will execute ls /home/site/wwwroot inside the container with ID 123456789abc, listing the contents of the /home/site/wwwroot directory.
Accessing the Shell:
To access an interactive shell within the container, you can use the -it option with a shell command such as bash or sh.
docker exec -it 123456789abc bash

This command will open an interactive Bash shell inside the container with ID 123456789abc.
